# Yii framework: UserLoginWidget

Tags: php, dialog, yii

I am trying to recreate the user login widget with the help of the CWidget and CJuiDialog.

When i click the login link the Dialog should open with the login form.

I used the example from : [Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/139/how-to-create-nice-modal-login-widget-with-a-cjuidialog/),
I understand most of it but i got stuck at this point. Not sure what this part of code means:

```
public function renderContent()
{
    $form=new User;
    if(isset($_POST['user']))
    {
        $form->attributes=$_POST['user'];
        if($form->validate() && $form->login()){
            $url = $this->controller->createUrl('site/index');
            $this->controller->redirect($url);
        }
    }
    $this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code with explanations:

```
public function renderContent()
{
    // Var to store data sent by client browser
    $form=new User;
    // Check if the post request has defined the user variable
    if(isset($_POST['user']))
    {
        // fill the $form attributes with the values sent by the web form in the post request
        $form->attributes=$_POST['user'];
        // validate the form data and then check if the data is valid to login the user
        // - the validate call is where the framework check if the data is valid
        //   against the model (e.g. user field must be text, not empty...)
        // - the login call is where you should encode your user validation, check for validity against the database or whatever you want
        if($form->validate() && $form->login()){
            // create the url where the client browser is going to be redirected
            $url = $this->controller->createUrl('site/index');
            // render a 302 redirection to the new page
            $this->controller->redirect($url);
        }
    }
    // if the request doesn't contain the 'user' variable, or if the validation/login calls have failed, render again the form. In the case of errors, they'll be shown in the 'errorSummary' section.
    $this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));
}
```

Comment: I am confused about this part $form=new `User;` Not sure what class to put there. I dont have a User class.

Comment: Well, you can do it all without classes, only using the POST variables and checking access directly, but the framework is designed to work this way when using forms, so is not a bad idea to create a model for user acess. If you've played with the [hello world app](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app), you can check there how the User class is extended from CFormModel and used.

Comment: I created a User modul. Now i get this error: UserLoginWidget cannot find the view "login".  My login page is under the views/site/login.php. Should i give it a direct path to it?

Comment: If you're going to use the login form as a widget, it means that you're going to reuse it in other parts project, so all the files needed by the widget must be in his folder, and for a view, in the ['views' subdirectory](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#getViewPath-detail).

Comment: Yes thats what i dont understand, i try to put the login.php in the same directory as the UserLoginWidget but still get the same error. EDIT: ah fixed it. made  a subdir in the models folder. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));
```

after this you have a file which name is login.php in component/view/login.php and you can access in your view like this...

```
<?php $this->widget('your class name'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function renderContent()
{
    $form=new User;//create User model
    if(isset($_POST['user']))// process when client submit (login)
    {
        $form->attributes=$_POST['user'];//add attribute from form in client
        if($form->validate() && $form->login()){//validate and check login using User class created in first line of this function
            $url = $this->controller->createUrl('site/index');//create url for redirect after login successfully
            $this->controller->redirect($url);
        }
    }
    $this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));//if it is not in submiting or login fail, we will go this code, it render the login form
}
```